# Acento y "ñ" en Access

Tags: c#, windows-forms, ms-access

Estoy insertando unos permisos en mi base de Access, los cuales los inserto correctamente, pero a la hora de mostrarme los datos en una aplicación de windows-forms se muestran así los caracteres:

> � quedandome "Clientes nuevos por d�a y a�o".

En la tabla los caracteres se guardan y se muestran correctamente.

¿Cuál puede ser la causa?

---

Este el código de mi aplicación:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Security.Business.Action>> groupActionsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Security.Business.Action>>();

foreach (Security.Business.Action action in this.actionManager.GetAllActions())
{
    if (action.Group == null)
        continue;

    if (!groupActionsDictionary.ContainsKey(action.Group.Name))
    {
        groupActionsDictionary.Add(action.Group.Name, new List<Security.Business.Action>());
    }

    groupActionsDictionary[action.Group.Name].Add(action);
}
foreach (string group in groupActionsDictionary.Keys.OrderBy(p => p))
{
    TreeNode groupNode = new TreeNode(group);
    groupNode.StateImageIndex = 0;
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(groupNode);
    foreach (Security.Business.Action action in groupActionsDictionary[group].OrderBy(p => p.Name))
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(action.Name);
        node.StateImageIndex = 0;
        node.Tag = action;
        groupNode.Nodes.Add(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Es muy probable que sea por el tipo de codificación al momento de leerlo. Para darte una respuesta más a detalle, ¿nos podrías compartir la línea con la cual estás leyendo esos valores?

Comment: Claro que si, lo lleno con un foreach de las acciones junto a sus grupos. Lo adjunte a la pregunta

Comment: @MarianoVelosodebrito Necesitamos más códigos. ¿De dónde sale `groupActionsDictionary` por ejemplo?

Comment: Este es el metodo completo @cnbandicoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontre el error, que dicho sea de paso no era un error. El INSERT a la tabla que estaba haciendo lo modificaba por un Notepadd++ y lo insertaba a la base mediante un script. Resulta que el notepad++ estaba mal. 
Para arreglar fui a: Codificacion -> Codificar en UTF-8 Sin BOM, volvi a correr el script en una base y ahora me aparece correctamente dentro del sistema.